# Power calculation of circuits

Tags: microcontroller, power, verification, 555

Please read on..... this looks long but is entry level and easy

I have done many simple projects based on microcontrollers but have not considered power and required current(for circuit to work) calculations. But now as I was doing my another project i.e., "8051 microcontroller development board" on a perf board, I found that not all the functional blocks(16x2LCD, max232 for serial comn, ADC0848, relays, etc) can work at the same time with same power supply since the current required was not enough for all of them to work.

So to make them work I added additional supplies and they were working quite perfectly. But now I know I was missing some serious power and current calculations, I had to do before I solder them. These calculations are important when you are designing or making any commercial product and also to save world's energy.

So I decided to calculate the power in a simple 555 timer astable circuit. The astable 555 timer is as shown

[image]

Vcc=5V, R1=R2=1Kohm, C=0.1uF

To calculate the power consumed I could directly find it through the multimeter but I want to calculate the power theoretically from the manufacturer's datasheet info.

NE555 datasheet is [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne555.pdf)

What have I done?

We know that power is:

$$ P = IV = I^2 R = {V^2 \over R} $$

So

1. power at trigger pin = max voltage at trigger * max current at trigger
   =2.2V(from the datasheet) x 2uA(from the datasheet) = 4.4μW
2. Output power = Max voltage time the current flowing through the load.
   Let's say the output is connected to LED with a 1Kohm resistor 
   Maximum output voltage when high =3.3V(from the datasheet) and current = 4.3mA(say when LED is connected to the output).
   So when the capacitor charges the output is high and when it discharges the output is low.
   low voltage maximum output = 0.4V, so I will calculate the power at output for one time period and then multiply for any time I run the circuit.
3. power at reset pin : Here we assume that the reset pin is always connected to Vcc=5V so the maximum power = max voltage * max current
   = 1V x 0.4mA = 0.4 mW
4. Power at control voltage = 0 since it is connected to a capacitor terminal whose other terminal is connected to ground.
5. I don't know how to calculate the power going into the Vcc pin. I know the functional block diagram and I dont think it's as simple as the voltage divider since the power has to be given to the opamp's, SR flip-flop etc.
6. Power dissipation in R1, R2 = (current through R1 or R2 squared) x (R1+R2)
   while charging and discharging. Since the current through these resistors are varying, so I thought to calculate the average current through charging and discharging and then find the power dissipated in one time period and than sum the power dissipation for one second.
7. power at threshold pin would be negligble beacuse the max current flowing into threshold pin is 250nA(from the datasheet)
8. How to calculate the power at discharge pin

I would now like to ask

1. Are all my values taken from the datasheet right for calculations? Or did I take some wrong values?
2. Are my calculations right?
3. Assuming things are right with above question then how can I move further.. that is power calculations with microcontrollers etc.

Thanks in advance for spending your valuable time and bearing with me

Comment: All this only to determine the power consumption ? **WHY ?** Why not build it on a breadboard and **measure** it ? You use a 555, there's also a 7555 or TLC555 these have the same functionality as a 555 but consume significantly less power (when configured properly).

Comment: Well, yes I can do that on the breadboard but the next steps I also would like to take is to determine the power consumption on pcb boards(beacuse I am learning pcb designing) too where I would add the power consumption of tracks on the board... and yes as of now I can do that on breadboard @FakeMoustache

Comment: *power consumption of tracks on the board* Explain to me how these **consume** power.

Comment: I think you are on the right track, but going overboard in trying to get things right.  The level of detail you are going into would be reasonable if you were trying to make a circuit run for as long as possible from a limited power source (small battery) but is way too involved if you are trying to figure out how large a power supply you will need.  You've gone from not calculating power use at all to trying to account for every electron.

Comment: Thats what I am telling.... I know it's copper and it does not consume much power but since I am a novice in PCB designing I should make sure from people here so that I can be sure of whatever I do..

Comment: And in my opinion: circuit design (and determining how much power a circuit uses) is **NOT** PCB design. I am a circuit designer, I do not design PCBs, I leave that to others. I **do** have to tell the PCB designer how much current is going to flow so (s)he can make the traces wide enough.

Comment: Just as a FYI for a 10 mil trace you're going to have about 4R per metre.

Comment: @JRE my aim is to design circuits which use as much less power as possible with 3.3V lithium batteries.... I am feeling good that I am on right track...

Comment: Oh, so you do know copper traces do not consume power ! I agree with JRE that you're going overboard on this. I understand that for a novice it is difficult to separate the important things from the less important things. If you would ask me, what does such a 555 timer consume, I'd suck my thumb and say 10 mA, probably a lot less. Even the thinnest trace on a PCB can support 10 mA so there's nothing special going on regarding a PCB design for this circuit.

Comment: *less power as possible with 3.3V* Then the 7555/TLC555 I mentioned is an option but there are also some low power micro controllers that can beat even these timers !

Comment: If you were to ask me how much the 555 consumes, I'd ask what it is driving as that will usually be far more than the 555 itself uses.  The linked datasheet says the 555 can provide up to 225mA (recommended to stay below 200mA,) so the load itself can be very significant.

Comment: I see @FakeMoustache.... you are so confident "I'd suck my thumb and say 10 mA" but after certain time I would study about the copper traces width and stuff... I also would like to say that there should be a community wiki question for copper traces width (formula and some important things since a book can be written on these things if I am not wrong )since these things get asked every other day on this site

Comment: If you go into google and put "Trace width calculator" there's literally hundreds. Most of which tell you the resistance of the traces at what width and what copper thickness at what temperature.

Comment: @Hayman thankyou for the info but I trust this site much than anyone and since this site is a place of every good question and many experts(also the ones who have commented) come here where at other places it is not possible. Due these experts we have best answers and therefore I wanted just one important question of the type.

Comment: Your confidence will also grow over the years as you gain experience. Don't worry too much about not knowing everything yet and try not to get lost in details (counting the electrons ;-) ). Instead, see what others do, what do their PCBs look like ? You can find many examples on the Internet. Are you familiar with the EEVBlog ? It is an excellent resource for (aspiring) PCB / circuit designers.

Comment: Yes I have recently found his videos on youtube, I like his every video and aspire to be like him....@FakeMoustache .... however I am looking for an answer to my question and assume that I will get one.

Comment: @JRE good pointer about the load current!

Comment: My two cents after reading all of this is that I think is this all based on a misconception; I very well maybe wrong, that was a lot of reading but.. Your 555 timer circuit (or any other circuit) will consume as much power as it needs (provided the power supply can deliver it [as you have found out]). So, read the data sheet(s) find the maximum power requirement, add the values for all your devices, multiply by some safety factor, get a power supplier that can deliver that much power, size traces components accordingly...

Comment: Thankyou for reading all this @Tyler .... but why do you think this is a misconception?

Comment: Misconception might not be the exact work I was looking for, but let me try to explain it this way... It would be difficult to account for where every single electron goes. With experience one should be able to estimate power consumed to some level of accuracy. Add in some safety margin. Now provide a power supply with enough power and you are done; the circuit is only going to take what it needs.

Comment: That's a very good idea @Tyler 1. Estimate power(not necessarily to very good accuracy but to required one) 2. add safety margin 3. Make sure the circuit works and you are done....Thankyou again!

Comment: Here's a 2-minute analysis.  555 timer with +5V supply consumes between 3mA and 6mA (section 6.5 in the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm555.pdf)).  The LED will consume 4.3mA (as mentioned in item #2 in the question).  The remaining currents are negligible.

Comment: Power isn't 'going in on the Vcc pin', that's CURRENT.  The way to know the power consumption is to check against measured current times voltage from the power supply.  You can measure more accurately than you can predict, more accurately than any datasheet will tell you.

Comment: So, Is that the total current flowing into VCC pin right? Also as you said all other currents are negligible which are quite convincing with my calculations. @Nick Alexeev Yes the load current varies as per our load but does the  current flowing into VCC pin varies when I connect load to it?

Comment: Yes I meant the current @Whit3rd. That is surely the easiest and accurate way of calculating current but as you can see the currents and voltages are varying in the capacitor and the resistors... I could not have calculated that with a multimeter so I had to use the calculations....

Answer (score 1):

The original issue was the over-taxing of the first power supply. Generally then you could use the max voltage/current supply figures from the 555 datasheet. Do the same for all the other expected devices. Many devices will have datasheets that you can use to approximate the actual power draw and that may be far below the maximum values. There may be a need to use separate power supplies for other than power delivery. i.e. to minimize noise in a high resolution ADC, or avoid using heat sinks ... etc.